# Custom url inside the button

Tags: users, uri, forms

I was creating my first project with drupal and now my problem was the **request new password** since this is a link and i want to make it into buttons so i generate my hook_form_alter but i got a problem with the url i'm not sure if markup is working.

Here my code for form_alter:

```
  $form['actions']['request'] = array(
'#markup' => l(t('Forgot Password?'), 'user/password', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'form-request','title' => t('Request a new generated password via e-mails.')))),'#weight' => 2, '#type' => 'button' );
```

I'm not sure if this is correct. Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: you want a linkable button instead of link?

Comment: ^ yeah sorry for my bad english :) actually the button is working but my problem it direct to login not in user/password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how your code should look like:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {
    $form['actions']['request'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Forgot Password?'),
      '#submit' => array('mycustom_submit_redirect'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('form-request'), 
        'title' => array(t('Request a new generated password via e-mails.')),
      ),
      '#weight' => 2, 
    );
  }
}

function mycustom_submit_redirect(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // sometimes it seems to fail
  //$form_state['redirect'] = 'user/password';

  // alternative method to redirect
  $options['absolute'] = TRUE;

  $url = url('user/password', $options);

  header('Location: ' . $url);

  drupal_exit($url);
}
```

Comment: still not working anyway i want to hook only at user_login_block

Comment: one thing i encounter are this no error message like this one "Username field is required.
Password field is required" but the url still /?q=node&destination=node

Comment: did you clear drupal cache after you implemented the new changes? Also did you replace FORM_ID with the desired form

Comment: replace `FORM_ID` with `user_login_block`

Comment: opps after i try it to other browser it direct only at /?q=node :(

Comment: I don't know why its doing it. However I changed the body of `mycustom_submit_redirect` function, check the answer.

Comment: @Aboodred1 : Your header() function needs some changes to make it a little more nice. Location header should be an absolute URL. Also, use drupal_goto() function - it will convert the given relative path to an absolute URL, sanitize it, send the correct location header and then **call `drupal_exit()`**.

Comment: @AyeshK I tried `drupal_goto()` it didn't work with me.   I will enhance `header()` function. Thanks